# Erro no onClick no Nextjs / React js

Tags: javascript, react, next.js

Na primeira tag `<Link>` está dando erro no `onClick` e não entendo o porque.

Por favor me ajudem:

```
import Link from 'next/link';
import React, { useState } from 'react';

export default function SignIn() {
  const [name, setName] = useState('');
  const [room, setRoom] = useState('');

  return (
    <div className="joinOuterContainer">
      <div className="joinInnerContainer">
        <h1 className="heading">Join</h1>
        <div>
          <input placeholder="Name" className="joinInput" type="text" onChange={(event) => setName(event.target.value)} />
        </div>
        <div>
          <input placeholder="Room" className="joinInput mt-20" type="text" onChange={(event) => setRoom(event.target.value)} />
        </div>
        <Link onClick = { e  =>  ( ! Nome  || ! Sala ) ? e . preventDefault ( ) : null }  to = { `/ chat? name = $ { name } & room = $ { room } ` }>
          <button className={'button mt-20'} type="submit">Sign In</button>
        </Link>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Erro:

> Type '{ children: Element; onClick: (e: any) => any; to: string; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & LinkProps & { children?: ReactNode; }'. Property 'onClick' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & LinkProps & { children?: ReactNode; }'.ts(2322)

Comment: que erro? detalhe mais a sua pergunta

Comment: o typescript responde:                                                                                                                
                                                                                                                                                   Type '{ children: Element; onClick: (e: any) => any; to: string; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & LinkProps & { children?: ReactNode; }'.
 Property 'onClick' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & LinkProps & { children?: ReactNode; }'.ts(2322)

Answer (score 1):

Este erro se deve ao fator de que `Link` não espera receber uma `props` chamada `onClick`. Podemos ver isso no próprio `type` usada pelo `Link`:

```
export declare type LinkProps = {
    href: Url;
    as?: Url;
    replace?: boolean;
    scroll?: boolean;
    shallow?: boolean;
    passHref?: boolean;
    prefetch?: boolean;
}
```

<sub>Este `type` está no arquivo `link.d.ts`. 
Pelo VSCode, você pode acessar o arquivo usando o comando <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Botão esquerdo do mouse</kbd>.</sub>

Ele também não espera receber um `props` de nome `to`, então ele também irá mostrar um erro pelo TypeScript.

**Repare que o atributo `href` é obrigatório**, como especificado na tipagem, então você teria que trabalhar com ele de alguma forma.

Nesse caso você teria que trabalhar com o `onClick` dentro de um componente filho dentro do `Link`, por exemplo no seu `button`, e esse `to`, acho que teriamos que usar o `href` no lugar dele.

Seria algo do tipo:

```html
<Link href={`/ chat? name = $ { name } & room = $ { room } `}>
  <button
    className={'button mt-20'}
    type="submit"
    onClick={(e: any) => (!name || !room ? e.preventDefault() : null)}
  >
    Sign In
  </button>
</Link>
```

<sub>Observe que passei um tipo `any` para o `e`.</sub>

Mas isso é só uma sugestão, pois não sei qual a intenção do seu código.

Comment: Muito obrigado, cara!!!

Answer (score 0):

Olhando seu código, tem vários espaços desnecessários, não sei se está assim ou foi ao colar na pergunta, mas, além disso, para passar o evento como parâmetro, deve declarar assim: `(e)`.

Ficaria assim:

```
<Link onClick={(e) =>  (! Nome || !Sala) ? e.preventDefault() : null } ........</Link>
```

Mas ainda assim não precisa desse ternário, porque não precisa do "null", bastaria fazer:
`if(! Nome || !Sala) e.preventDefault();`

Comment: Muito obrigado, cara!!!